# How to use ajax to link with a div tag on a seperate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I just need a bit of help using ajax. What I have at the moment is a button image of a plus sign. Now when the user clicks on the button image, it will open up a model window. At the moment the modal window is blank.

The reason the modal window is blank is because I have not corrctly linked it up with the div tag "previouslink", as it is on a seperate page. (previousquestions.php). I want the modal window to display the details within the "previouslink" div tag in the "previousquestions.php" page, but how can this be achieved using ajax?

Below is the code of the modal window and the image button in the page (QandATable.php):

```
    <script>

      function plusbutton()
        {

        $(".previouslink").modal("previousquestions.php");          
        return false;
    }

    </script>

    <body>

    <h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS</h1>

    <table id="plus" align="center">
    <tr>
    <th>
    <a onclick="return plusbutton();">
    <img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage"/>
    </a>
    <span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>
    </th>
    </tr>
    </table>

<div class="previouslink">
</div>

    </body>
```

Below is the "previouslink" div tag which is in the "previousquestions.php" page:

```
<button type="button" id="close" onclick="return closewindow();">Close</button>
<h1>PREVIOUS QUESTIONS</h1>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
      <p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" /></p>
      <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which modal plugin do you use? I would suggest you take a look at its documentation, as most of these already have the ability to load content via AJAX.

But regardless of that, I think there is a misconception here: you basically tell jQuery *"Take the element with the class 'previouslink', and make it into a modal window"* - but there is no element with that class on the current page (QandATable.php).

EDIT: for simpleModal, it should work like this:

```
$.modal( $('<div />').load('previousquestions.php .previouslink') );
```

Comment: Hi, I am using simpleModal from Eric Martin. I will test this and get back to you :)

Comment: OK, I still havn't got the modal window to display the contents from "previousquestions.php" page but I updated code above so you can see what is happening now

Comment: @user1394925 I've updated my answer with something that should work for you. You can remove the `<div class='previouslink'></div>` from QandATable.php again - simpleModal works differently than I thought. My updated code simply loads everything from previousquestions.php, takes only what is inside `<div class='previouslink'>` on _that_ page, and hands it to `$.modal` to display it.